# Copying cell contents based on header value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I've got two sheets,
Sheet-1 contains columns of names between 7:61 with the header of said columns being dates (the Monday at the start of the week).

In the second sheet(sheet-2), I've got 3 columns which contain headers that reflect the Monday of the current week that the sheet is opened and the two weeks following. It's worth noting that this part is already setup.

What I'm wanting for example's sake, is when I open this on the 9th of May 2017, sheet-2 is displaying the Monday of that week in the first column (08/05/2017) and it has pulled cells 7:61 from sheet-1 that sit under the date 08/05/2017.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in first column of sheet 2 to get the previous Monday's date.

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-2)
```

afterwards use an index, match formula to pull in the correct info from rows `7:61` corresponding to the date.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to figure it out, I just nested *a lot* of IF functions in a singular cell and dragged the formula down.

If someone does come up with a simpler method I'd love to hear it!

Comment: You might actually [edit] this answer and add the actual detail, logic, etc. you actually used to make it helpful to others.